# Load/Reload resource bundle in Struts2

Tags: struts2

Trying to override the resource bundle in Struts 2 application outside of the war, but this does not seem to work. I wrote my own custom `ResourceControl` which overrides

`newBundle (Loading from my custom location)`, `getTimeToLive (with my own interval)` and `needsReload` methods.

The resource bundle works well outside of Struts2 in a standalone application. In Struts2 tried to register my own bundle in impl of ServletContextListener

```
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
  ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("myresources", defaultLocale,new MyControl());
  LocalizedTextUtil.setDelegatedClassLoader(bundle.getClass().getClassLoader()); 
}
```

Objective is to refresh the bundle at certain intervals and load the new labels in the application without a restart.

Question/issue is, I am unable to register my custom bundle & refresh it.

Thanks!

Comment: And the question is...? Also read documentation about `LocalizedTextUtil.setDelegatedClassLoader`.